# On the Wigner symmetry representation theorem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, symmetry, unitarity

[Wigner symmetry representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%27s_theorem#Statement) tells that if $\mathcal{S}:\mathbb{P}\mathcal{H}\to \mathbb{P}\mathcal{H}$ is a symmetry, then $\mathcal{S}[\Psi]=[\hat{U}\Psi]$ where $\hat{U}:\mathcal{H}\to \mathcal{H}$ is either a linear unitary operator or an antilinear antiunitary operator. But the linear unitary operator $\hat{U}$ is not unique, because for all $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$, $e^{i\theta}\hat{U}$ also does the job. My question is that if there is another linear operator $\hat{V}:\mathcal{H}\to \mathcal{H}$ for which $\mathcal{S}[\Psi]=[\hat{V}\Psi]$, is $\hat{V}$ unitary as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that by the brackets you mean the equivalence class of the state, that is, $[\psi]\in\mathbb{PH}$ is the ray to which $\psi\in\mathbb{H}$ belongs. Now, if your question is whether *every operator compatible with a symmetry is (anti-)unitary*, then **the answer is yes, and it is so by definition**. In fact, the whole point of Wigner's theorem is to prove the converse, namely that for any symmetry transformation there is an (anti-)unitary operator that is compatible with it.

A bijection $S: \mathbb{PH}\to \mathbb{PH}$ is *defined* to be a symmetry transformation if it preserves the product of rays, that is, if $S$ is bijective and

$$S[\psi]\cdot S[\phi] = [\psi]\cdot[\phi].\tag{$1$}$$

Consequently, if $S$ is a symmetry and $V: \mathbb{H}\to\mathbb{H}$ is such that

$$S[\psi] = [V\psi]\tag{$2$}$$

then by definition of both symmetry and the ray product

$$[\psi]\cdot [\phi] := \frac{|\langle\psi, \phi\rangle|}{\|\psi\|\|\phi\|}\tag{$3$}$$

we have

$$\frac{|\langle V\psi, V\phi\rangle|}{\|V\psi\|\|V\phi\|}
\stackrel{(3)}{=}[V\psi]\cdot [V\phi] \stackrel{(2)}{=} S[\psi]\cdot S[\phi]
\stackrel{(1)}{=}[\psi]\cdot [\phi] = \frac{|\langle\psi, \phi\rangle|}{\|\psi\|\|\phi\|}.$$

This only holds for any two states if and only if
$$\langle V\psi, V\phi\rangle
= \langle\psi, \phi\rangle\quad\text{or}\quad
\langle V\psi, V\phi\rangle
= \langle\psi, \phi\rangle^*.$$

You might wonder why $\langle V\psi, V\phi\rangle
= e^{i\theta}\langle\psi, \phi\rangle$ for arbitrary $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ is not an option, but note that in that case we would have

$$\frac{|\langle V\psi, V\phi\rangle|}{\|V\psi\|\|V\phi\|}
=\frac{|e^{i\theta}\langle \psi, \phi\rangle|}{\sqrt{e^{i2\theta}\langle \psi, \psi\rangle\langle \phi, \phi\rangle}}
= e^{-i\theta} \frac{|\langle\psi, \phi\rangle|}{\|\psi\|\|\phi\|}.$$

Actually, this later possibility is absurd in deeper ways, since for any $\theta\neq 0$ it  would imply that $\langle V\psi, V\psi\rangle \not\in \mathbb{R}^{\geq0}$, which attempts against the definition of inner product.

Comment: I really appreciate your help and nice explanation. I got it now. Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Sorry to ask another question. Let $S=1$ the indenity function on $PH$ and $U_1$ denotes the corresponding unitary operator (i.e. 1$[\psi]=[U_1 \psi]$). Can we conclude that $U_1\circ U_1=U_1$? The same question for $f\in PH$: Is $U_f \circ U_{f^{-1}}=U_1$?

Comment: I believe you could not conclude that it is the identity, because what Wigner's theorem guarantees you is only that, for a symmetry $f$ and its associated unitary operator $U_f$, you will have $[\psi] = f^\circ f^{-1}[\psi] = [U_f U_{f^{-1}}\psi]$. Consequently, the most you can say is that $U_f U_{f^{-1}}$ maps $\psi$ to some $e^{i\theta}\psi$,  for a possibly non zero $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$, because by definition the elements of a ray $[\psi]$ can differ from each other by a phase factor.

Comment: Of course, if we have an operator $U$ compatible with a symmetry $S$, then $e^{i \theta}$ for $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ is compatible with $S$ too. This apparent subtlety is actually critical, because even though two states differing by a phase factor lead to the same physics, the phases are relevant to linear combinations of states (in the same way the direction of a vector is crucial for vector addition), which are absolutely essential for quantum mechanics.

Comment: You are right. I understood it now. Thank you very much for the comments and the time you have devoted to answer my questions.